# Format SQL table removing 0's and grouping them based on years

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I have a table which I want to format. The query being used for the table is

```
select x.year,
round(avg(case when c.mark >= 50 and x.term = 'S1' then 1 else 0 
end)::numeric,2) as s1_pass_rate,
round(avg(case when c.mark >= 50 and x.term = 'S2' then 1 else 0 
end)::numeric,2) as s2_pass_rate
from course_enrolments c join
courses s
on c.course = s.id
join semesters x on s.semester = x.id
where s.subject in (select id from subjects where name = 'COMP SYS') and 
c.mark IS NOT NULL
group by x.year, x.term;
```

It generates the following table:

```
year | s1_pass_rate | s2_pass_rate
------+--------------+--------------
2003 |         1.00 |         0.00
2003 |         0.00 |         1.00
2004 |         1.00 |         0.00
2004 |         0.00 |         0.85
2005 |         1.00 |         0.00
2005 |         0.00 |         1.00
2006 |         1.00 |         0.00
2006 |         0.00 |         1.00
```

I want to format it to:

```
year | s1_pass_rate | s2_pass_rate
------+--------------+--------------
03 |         1.00 |         1.00
04 |         1.00 |         0.85
05 |         1.00 |         1.00
06 |         1.00 |         1.00
```

Not sure how to group the years like that and remove values with 0.00. Please help me with this. Thanks

Comment: Are you using MySQL or SQL Server?  They are very different databases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try grouping by the year alone (not the term), and then take the sum of each of the two pass rate columns.  The zero will effectively no-op in that summation, leaving you with the non zero values you want.  Try the following query:

```
SELECT RIGHT(CONVERT(varchar(4), t.year), 2)
       SUM(t.s1_pass_rate) AS s1_pass_rate,
       SUM(t.s2_pass_rate) AS s2_pass_rate
FROM
(
    SELECT x.year,
           ROUND(AVG(CASE WHEN c.mark >= 50 AND x.term = 'S1'
                              THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)::NUMERIC, 2) AS s1_pass_rate,
           ROUND(AVG(CASE WHEN c.mark >= 50 AND x.term = 'S2'
                              THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)::NUMERIC, 2) AS s2_pass_rate
    FROM course_enrolments c
    INNER JOIN courses s
        ON c.course = s.id
    INNER JOIN semesters x
        ON s.semester = x.id
    WHERE s.subject in (SELECT id FROM subjects WHERE name = 'COMP SYS') AND
          c.mark IS NOT NULL
    GROUP BY x.year, x.term
) t
GROUP BY t.year
```

Comment: Do you know how to trim 2006 to 06?

Comment: Use `RIGHT(CONVERT(varchar(4), 2004), 2)` ... you may have to play around with this a bit, but this is how I would do it.